# Visual Studio Server Explorer Table icons legend

Tags: sql-server, icons

I notice that SQL Server Explorer displays(at least) two different icons for the tables in a database, and cannot figure out what is different between the two icons.

Thanks
Anand

Comment: screenshot? i've only ever seen 1 icon.

Answer (score 0):

I have to read your mind.
Could that be due to tables of a linked server?

Comment: No, they are all from the same server. However, when I linked up the foreign keys the icons all became the same - weird.